# HTML 5 FileList - jsRender

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

Using the new HTML 5 File API, i'm trying to pass the files the user selects to a template (rendered with jsRender). Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/jsrender.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(':file').change(function() {
        //$('#files-placeholder').html($('#files-template').render({ files: [ { name: 'Test 1' }, { name: 'Test 2' } ] }));
        $('#files-placeholder').html($('#files-template').render({ files: this.files }));
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input name="files" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <script id="files-template" type="text/x-jsrender">
      <ul>
        {{for files}}
          <li>{{>name}}</li>
        {{/for}}
      </ul>
    </script>
    <div id="files-placeholder"></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

However it doesn't work as expected. For demonstration if you try rendering the template with the commented out line then it works fine.

I'd appreciate it if someone could show me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error? What do you mean by not working?

Comment: I renders a list with one item. I'll edit my question to make it easier for you to test.

Comment: Make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if possible

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4m3YQ/ - Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the templating engine works for real arrays only, not `FileList`s

I fixed it here http://jsfiddle.net/4m3YQ/5/

Convert to array like this:

```
[].slice.call(this.files)
```